# berkshelf unable to connect on CentOS

Tags: networking, centos, vagrant, chefdk

I installed ChecfDK on the vagrant box.

Brekshelf is not work well. Uable to connet Unable to connect

I checked Iptables, etc, but could not find the problem on the network.
URL is asccesable by curl, and work fine on ubuntu box.

CentOS (https://github.com/takase1024/chefdk-centos)

```
[vagrant@vagrant-centos65 ~]$ cd /vagrant/berks
[vagrant@vagrant-centos65 berks]$ berks install
Resolving cookbook dependencies...
Fetching 'myapp' from source at .
Fetching cookbook index from http://api.berkshelf.com/...
Error retrieving universe from source: http://api.berkshelf.com/
  * [Berkshelf::APIClient::TimeoutError] Unable to connect to: http://api.berkshelf.com/
E, [2014-08-25T03:14:08.122005 #1776] ERROR -- : Actor crashed!
Berkshelf::MissingLockfileCookbookVersion: Cookbook 'apache2' (2.0.0) not found in any of the sources! This can happen if the remote cookbook has been deleted or if the sources inside the Berksfile have changed. Please run `berks update apache2` to resolve to a valid version.
        /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/berkshelf/lib/berkshelf/installer.rb:95:in `install'
        /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0.pre2/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:26:in `public_send'
        /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0.pre2/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:26:in `dispatch'
        /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0.pre2/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:63:in `dispatch'
        /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0.pre2/lib/celluloid/cell.rb:60:in `block in invoke'
        /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0.pre2/lib/celluloid/cell.rb:71:in `block in task'
        /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0.pre2/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:369:in `block in task'
        /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0.pre2/lib/celluloid/tasks.rb:55:in `block in initialize'
        /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0.pre2/lib/celluloid/tasks/task_fiber.rb:15:in `block in create'
E, [2014-08-25T03:14:08.123992 #1776] ERROR -- : Actor crashed!
Berkshelf::MissingLockfileCookbookVersion: Cookbook 'iptables' (0.13.2) not found in any of the sources! This can happen if the remote cookbook has been deleted or if the sources inside the Berksfile have changed. Please run `berks update iptables` to resolve to a valid version.
        /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/berkshelf/lib/berkshelf/installer.rb:95:in `install'
        /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0.pre2/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:26:in `public_send'
        /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0.pre2/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:26:in `dispatch'
        /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0.pre2/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:63:in `dispatch'
        /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0.pre2/lib/celluloid/cell.rb:60:in `block in invoke'
        /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0.pre2/lib/celluloid/cell.rb:71:in `block in task'
        /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0.pre2/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:369:in `block in task'
        /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0.pre2/lib/celluloid/tasks.rb:55:in `block in initialize'
        /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0.pre2/lib/celluloid/tasks/task_fiber.rb:15:in `block in create'
Cookbook 'apache2' (2.0.0) not found in any of the sources! This can happen if the remote cookbook has been deleted or if the sources inside the Berksfile have changed. Please run `berks update apache2` to resolve to a valid version.

(Following omitted)

[vagrant@vagrant-centos65 berks]$ curl http://api.berkshelf.com/
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
  <head>

(Following omitted)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying to use the Berkshelf workflow I came to figure out that it doesn't really work on vagrant (or I guess Virtual Box?) CentOS guests running on a Windows Host. This is because of the timeout issue as pointed out above. My hacky fix was this. I know its probably would be better to push an enhancement that allows you to pass this is as a variable.

Now I am assuming you are using ChefDK's embedded ruby and berkshelf gem. If not, the locations might be in other places.

Read more about the particular class here:

http://ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/b/berkshelf-api-client-1.2.0/Berkshelf/APIClient/Connection.html

```
[vagrant@vagrant-centos65 apache-acquity]$ cd /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/berkshelf-api-client-1.2.0/
lib/berkshelf/api_client
[vagrant@vagrant-centos65 api_client]$ vim connection.rb
```

Find this:

```
def initialize(url, options = {})
  options         = options.reverse_merge(retries: 3, retry_interval: 0.5,
    open_timeout: 3, timeout: 30)
```

and change to this:

```
def initialize(url, options = {})
  options         = options.reverse_merge(retries: 3, retry_interval: 0.5,
    open_timeout: 30, timeout: 30)
```

Save and close and try it again.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it might be an issue with the options for the berkshelf-api-client. By default the open_timeout option is set to 3 seconds. I was able to get a successful connection by increasing this timeout.

```
1.9.3-p547 :010 > source = Berkshelf::Source.new("http://berkshelf.example.come")
 => #<Berkshelf::Source uri: "http://berkshelf.example.com">
1.9.3-p547 :011 > api = source.send(:api_client)
 => #<Berkshelf::APIClient::Connection:0x00000001b613f8 @url="http://berkshelf.example.com", @retries=3, @retry_interval=0.5, @parallel_manager=nil, @headers={"User-Agent"=>"Faraday v0.9.0"}, @params={}, @options=#<Faraday::RequestOptions timeout=30, open_timeout=3>, @ssl=#<Faraday::SSLOptions (empty)>, @default_parallel_manager=nil, @builder=#<Faraday::RackBuilder:0x00000001b612b8 @handlers=[Ridley::Middleware::ParseJson, Ridley::Middleware::Gzip, Faraday::Request::Retry, Faraday::Adapter::NetHttp]>, @url_prefix=#<URI::HTTP:0x000000023938a0 URL:http://berkshelf.example.com/>, @proxy=nil>
1.9.3-p547 :012 > api.universe
```

Error:

```
Berkshelf::APIClient::TimeoutError: Unable to connect to: http://berkshelf.example.com
```

Now, if I modify the options used by the APIClient as follows:

```
1.9.3-p547 :012 > opts = api.options
 => #<Faraday::RequestOptions timeout=30, open_timeout=3>
1.9.3-p547 :013 > opts.open_timeout = 30
 => 30
1.9.3-p547 :014 > api.instance_eval { @options = opts }
 => #<Faraday::RequestOptions timeout=30, open_timeout=30>
```

Success:

```
1.9.3-p547 :015 > api.universe
 => [#<Berkshelf::APIClient::RemoteCookbook:0x00000002a30320 @blah=blah @etc=true>]
```

Comment: I are not familiar with ruby. 
Do you want to experiment your way how if you run the command? 

I had forgotten to push the sample code. 
Was just Push.

Comment: this is showing the ruby interactive shell or "irb". So just run "irb" from the command line then when irb opens type 'require berkshelf'. Then you can complete the exercise above.